# TypeError: a.wrapper is undefined

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I'm using swiper.js, but I get this error:

TypeError: a.wrapper is undefined

I'm not really suer why it's telling me a.wrapper is undefined, I don't think I use that in my code.

http://store-de.hugoboss.com/boss-herrenmode/

If you open up console in the browser you will see the error.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not providing any code but a page in which I can't see any errors like that. Could you please elaborate your question a little bit more?

Comment: sorry if you open console in the browser you can see it

Comment: @user1937021: (Your question is good candidate to close) Questions seeking debugging help __("why isn't this code working?")__ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce __it in the question itself.__ Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok close it then I'll redo the question

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps because `var s2length= $('.s2 .swiper-wrapper').children().length;` isn't working because `'.s2 .swiper-wrapper'` isn't on the page?

There's a lot of code there to siphon through...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my `.swiper-wrapper` was actually called `.slider-wrapper`, which is incorrect.